# How to Identify whether document following CDA or CCD format?

Tags: medical, ccd, cda, hl7-cda, c-cda

I'm working on retrieving data from clinical document(cda or ccd). I want to identify whether the document is CDA or CCD. I check the MDHT Java api but I didn't find related.

Answer (score 2):

The new standard per meaningful use stage 2 is C-CDA and all EHR vendors must comply to remain "certified". You really shouldn't be encountering too many CCRs.

Also not too sure why MDHT is being used when resources such as bluebutton+ (originally VA and now an initiative through the ONC) is far more simplistic and the js in their library will parse most forms of C-CDA. Check their resources - https://github.com/blue-button/bluebutton.js/

Check this resource as well - http://ccda-scorecard.smartplatforms.org/static/ccdaScorecard/#/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to clarify your use of CDA and CCD (Did you mean CCR) - CCD stands for Continuity of Care Document which there are two version - the latest being part of the consolidated standard from hl7 - CCD is a CDA

MDHT has both implemented and you can use the CDAUtil.load on the document resource;  MDHT will return a java object of the document type and the use an instanceof to check the type of document

```
ClinicalDocument clinicalDocument = CDAUtil.load(new FileInputStream("somedocument.xml"), result);
        if (clinicalDocument instanceof ContinuityOfCareDocument) {
                // Do something here
        }
```

Here is a simple document processing framework using MDHT https://www.projects.openhealthtools.org/integration/viewvc/viewvc.cgi/trunk/examples/org.openhealthtools.mdht.cda.processor/?root=mdht-models&system=exsy1002

Comment: I checked object type of generated clinicalDocument it showing ClinicalDocumentImpl. so we can't differentiate it. any more suggestions?

Comment: do you have the imp guide run time jars in the class path? (consol,hits,..) see http://sourceforge.net/projects/oht-modeling/files/Nightly%20Builds/Runtime/ Call the CDAUtils.loadLibraries()

Comment: Call CDAUtils.loadLibraries before loading to init the run time

Comment: can we differentiate CCD and CDA by template ids? or parsing by xsd?